# Measure derivatives and the chain rule

Tags: integration, measure-theory, continuity, geometric-measure-theory

Let $\mu$ and $\lambda$ be Radon measures on $\mathbb{R^n}$ such that $\mu << \lambda$. Prove that

$\displaystyle \int D(\mu,\lambda,x)^2 d\lambda x= \int D(\mu,\lambda,x)d\mu x$.

Is it possible to do

$\begin{align} \int D(\mu,\lambda,x)^2 d\lambda x &= \int D(\lambda, \mu,x)^{-1} D(\mu,\lambda,x) d\lambda x \\ &= \int D(\lambda, \mu,x)^{-1} d\mu x \\ &= \int D(\mu,\lambda,x) d\mu x \end{align}$

Otherwise I cannot see how you would do a substitution.

Comment: That is correct, but you do not have to write $D(\mu, \lambda, x)$ as $D(\lambda, \mu, x)^{-1}$. The only thing you do with this is to substitute it back in the last step. It is even not really correct, because you do not know $\lambda << \mu$.

Comment: Im not entirely sure what you mean

Comment: I mean that you can just write \begin{eqnarray*}
\int\left[D\left(\mu,\lambda,x\right)\right]^{2}\, d\lambda\left(x\right) & = & \int D\left(\mu,\lambda,x\right)\cdot D\left(\mu,\lambda,x\right)\, d\lambda\left(x\right)\\
 & = & \int D\left(\mu,\lambda,x\right)\, d\mu\left(x\right),
\end{eqnarray*}
if $D\left(\mu,\lambda,x\right)$ denotes the Radon-Nikodym derivative
$\frac{d\mu}{d\lambda}\left(x\right)$.

Comment: What gives the right to almost regard $D(\mu,\lambda,x)$ as a constant. This doesnt seem like a rigorous proof, it seems more like a calculus method (I may be wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let me give you a detailed answer:

By definition of the Radon-Nikodym derivative, you have

$$
\int \chi_A (x) \, d\mu(x) = \mu(A) = \int_A D(\mu, \lambda, x) d\lambda(x) = \int \chi_A (x) \cdot  D(\mu, \lambda, x) d\lambda(x)
$$

for every measurable set $A$. By linearity, this just means

$$
\int f(x) \, d\mu(x) = \int f(x) \cdot D(\mu, \lambda, x)\,d\lambda(x) \qquad \qquad (\dagger)
$$

for every simple (nonnegative) function $f : X \rightarrow [0,\infty]$. Using a standard monotone convergence argument, this implies that $(\dagger)$ is also true for all non-negative, measurable functions $f :X \to [0,\infty]$.

Now take $f = D(\mu, \lambda, x)$.